# How can I color points in a range in a dataset on a scatterplot in R

Tags: r, colors, subset, scatter-plot

I need to make a color-coded scatter plot from imported data where values between 0 and 4 are colored red. I tried subsetting but I don't think I'm using it correctly. Heres the code I'm trying to use

```
DAT1 = log(DAT, 10)
data.frame(DAT1)
FSC = DAT1$FSC.HLin
RED = DAT1$RED.V.HLin
plot(FSC, RED)
red = subset(DAT1, FSC.HLin<4 & FSC.HLin>0)
points(red)
col = 'red'
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of plotting the selected points in a different color with `ifelse`. Set graphics parameter `col` to the values `"red"` and `"black"` depending on the x axis values.

```
FSC <- -5:10
RED <- seq_along(FSC)
plot(FSC, RED, col = ifelse(FSC > 0 & FSC < 4, "red", "black"))
```

[image]

Another, equivalent way is to create a vector of colors beforehand. In the code that follows I also change the point character to solid circle, though this is not in the question. And use the data set `DAT1` directly without creating new vectors `FSC` and `RED`.

```
DAT1 <- data.frame(FSC.HLin = FSC, RED.V.HLin = RED)
col <- with(DAT1, ifelse(FSC.HLin > 0 & FSC.HLin < 4, "red", "black"))
pch <- with(DAT1, ifelse(FSC.HLin > 0 & FSC.HLin < 4, 16, 1))
plot(RED.V.HLin ~ FSC.HLin, data = DAT1, col = col, pch = pch)
```

[image]